# SailsJs 0.10 using with WebSocket Sails.io (socket.io). How to do? Sailscast ep. 21

Tags: sails.js

In this screencast for SailsJs 0.9.x I don't understand how to do the same real time events with the version of SailsJs 0.10.x.

http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/10/10/building-a-sails-application-ep21-integrating-socket-dot-io-and-sails-with-custom-controller-actions-using-real-time-model-events/

Can you help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can either wait until they do the same screencast for 0.10, or look to http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Upgrading, search for socket there and you'll see the differences, ooooor, you could just use angular-sails-bind and use socket transparently in your angular app. :)

https://github.com/diegopamio/angular-sails-bind

I made it for my own project and then decided to put it as a separated library so everybody could benefit and I could have my first experience developing a bower package.

I hope it could help you.

Comment: Can you have a look on this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37129766/how-to-use-sails-io-js-version-0-11-3-in-node-server